Is there a way to ignore the "STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE" clause when doing a schema compare in Visual Studio?
I have a database project in my Visual Studio (2022) solution that I just synced to the live database, which is in SQL Azure. My dev database is in a local SQL Server instance (2019, I think). When I run the schema compare in Visual Studio with the project as the source and the local DB as the target, it shows a ton of tables are out-of-sync, but they only differ because the Azure db has the "WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = ON)" clause on the CONSTRAINT line. For example:

My questions are:

Is there any way to prevent "schema compare" from adding this? Turning the "Statistics" option off didn't do anything.

Will it hurt anything if I just update the SQL Server 2019 instance with the Azure version of the table definitions? I'm not a dba so that STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE doesn't mean anything to me.



You should understand why that option was set in Azure. and whether it is still intentional that it is disabled, The effect of getting your dev instance reflecting prod is that you will have to update stats manually on your dev instance too if you want them updated. (out of date stats can cause poor execution plans for queries)


Is there any way to prevent "schema compare" from adding this? Turning the "Statistics" option off didn't do anything.

AFAIK Unfortunately, in Visual Studio's schema compare tool, there is no built-in way to ignore specific differences like the WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = ON) clause. The Statistics option you're referring to only affects actual statistics objects, not table constraints or index options like STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE.
To avoid these differences in schema comparisons you can choose not to apply those specific changes when applying the schema update by manually reviewing the generated SQL and excluding the changes related to STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE.


Will it hurt anything if I just update the SQL Server 2019 instance with the Azure version of the table definitions? I'm not a dba so that STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE doesn't mean anything to me.


STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE is an index option that prevents SQL Server from automatically updating statistics for a table or index. Statistics help the SQL Server query optimizer to determine the most efficient way to execute a query.

Turning off auto-updates (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = ON) could cause performance degradation if the statistics become stale over time.

If you apply WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = ON) to your local SQL Server 2019 instance, it won't immediately harm anything, but you should be mindful of potential performance issues if the table's data changes frequently
data changes frequently.

Thanks for the info. I was manually reviewing the changes, but having to do that for every table is kind of a pain. That's why I was thinking maybe I would just update the 2019 version to match the Azure server so I'd only have to deal with it once. Quick follow-up question, if you happen to know: why are the two versions of SQL Server generating different table scripts anyway? Is one more "correct" than the other? I don't know why the Azure version has the STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE set to ON. Is that a normal default for SQL Azure?
